# How to map user generated forms into a database?

Tags: forms, database-design

I want users to be able to make forms with N fields, text, numbers, e-mail, combo, etc. How do i store each field without knowing how many of them will be?
The first way i thought of doing this is storing all the text fields in one table, all e-mail fields in another, etc. Then, in a table i store the form information with it's own ID.
How do i work around scalability in this form system? For example having multiple servers sharing forms.
Is my design good enough?
What do i need to store to transform then into html with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

- Create a clean, normalized database structure (avoid [EAV Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model))
- Store meta data (like XML etc.) in the database

**1. Solution**:

**forms table**:

```
id | user_id | name
```

- user_id: The "owner" of this form
- name: The name of the form like "Registration" or whatever

**form_fields table**:

```
id | form_id | label | type | sorting | values | default
```

- form_id is a foreign key to the forms table
- label is the Label for the input like "Password"
- type is the input type (like select, email, password, text), based on this you can handle the displaying / validation etc.
- sorting gives you the ability to arrange fields in a form
- values - predefined values example is a select box, store this as meta data like xml,json or whatever and parse it in your application, you can use the type field to determine how you want to handle these values
- default - a default value (maybe a selected value in a select box or pre-defined text for a text input)

if someone fills out a form:

**filled_forms table**:

```
id | user_id | form_id
```

- user_id: who filled the form?
- form_id: which form?

**filled_form_values**:

```
id | filled_form_id | field_id | values
```

- filled_form_id: foreign key to filled_forms table
- field_id: the field id of the form
- values: the entered values, maybe store as metadata like JSON, XML (example: a select box which allows multiple selections) you can join the form and the form field so you get the type of the field and then you can handle the values properly

Pros:

- The database handles data integrity for you
- Normalized database schema

Cons:

- Static schema, multiple joins to retrieve fields
- Goes in the direction of a EAV-Model
- No direct transformation with XSLT possible

**2. Solution**:

You have only two tables:

**forms table**:

```
id | user_id | name | metadata
```

- user_id: Owner of the form (foreign key)
- name: Name of the form (like Registration etc.)
- metadata: Your self-implemented description of the form (HTML,XML,JSON whatever) which describes the form properly, giving IDs to the elements etc.

**filled_forms table**:

id | form_id | user_id | values

- form_id: Foreign-Key to the form
- user_id: Foreign-Key to the user who filled out the form
- values: Your self-implemented description of the filled out form (HTML, XML, JSON whatever) which describes the input and maps it to the fields correctly

Pros:

- Very flexible, no EAV trap, simple structure
- Direct transformation with XSLT possible

Cons:

- You have to ensure data integrity by your own

Comment: i'll go with the second solution, also, what solution do you think is less resource intensive? Ensuring data integrity + updating the metadata or stressing the db with the first solution?